# argument is not passed to handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, this, helper

I am new to handlebars, and trying to pass this as an argument to a custom helper. Pretty simple task, but in the helper, it turns out to be 0. Why doesn't it work? Here's helper:

```
hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('createAddressLink', function(address) {
    console.log(address);
  return `<li class="search-bar-container__content-item">
            <a href="/address/${address.getID()}" class="search-bar-container__address-link link">
                ${address.getName()}
            </a>
        </li>`
})
```

Here's how I pass argument to it:

```
{{#each addresses}}
                {{createAddressLink this}}
            {{/each}}
```

Comment: First of all, I don't think this is a good use case for a helper. Since it contains HTML markup, it is better as a template or a partial. As it is, the HTML it returns is going to be escaped - you would need to use `Handlebars.SafeString` to prevent that. However, none of that accounts for why you are getting an `address` object in your helper function. I don't see any reason why that part shouldn't work. Have you confirmed that the value of `addresses` is what you intend it to be?

Comment: Here is an example using your helper (with the Handlebars.SafeString utility added) that renders as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/8f3dtz2v/

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It really works as needed, the problem was in logic